# 404 Error on images on Github pages, but image paths working locally

Tags: javascript, image, file, canvas, directory

I've seen answers here so I checked to make sure the spelling is the same and case sensitive but I can't seem to get this to work on git pages although it all works fine locally.

Here are pictures of my console log, and of my directory, and where/how images are called in my js files:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFkGs.jpg

Update: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sPQ2.jpg , okay so here, I have images missing but I'm not sure why? I'm new to github so I might be missing something, in my repo the folder for images has everything, where does one update the structure that github pages seesuses?

Comment: apologies, I added the images of code where I made the image calls, which are from my js files so I think thats where the issue is, I could definitely be wrong

Comment: https://imgur.com/5tqfFe3 , okay so here, I have images missing but I'm not sure why? I'm learning github so I might be missing something, in my repo the folder for images has everything, where does one update the structure that github pages sees?

Comment: sorry if I’m xk conveying my issue wrong, in the OP link, you can see the github image folder, and the folder on my local directory where everything is working fine, in the last link I show you, serveral images that are on my local and github aren’t In the images folder in the github page